# Iphone Portraits mode switching back to landscape Mode is not Working Automatically

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ios7, uiinterfaceorientation

[image]My app launches in Portraits mode correctly and works great , But in my Application Some Views Support Landscape mode only and some Both landscape and Portraits, when i Switch the application view  from Only Landscape Supported to some view  that support  both orientation and rotate the Device to Portraits and Hit The Back Button , the Landscape view is not rotated Automatically

i use the following code  to set the orientation

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return YES;
}


- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return YES;
}




- (NSInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeLeft;
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Edit these lines

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return YES;
}
```

As

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    if (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeLeft) {
        return YES;
    }
    else {
        return NO;
    }
}
```